# How do I check if values in array are in between a max and min and then do something

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello I am having problems checking if my values are in between the max and min tolerances and if so to do something. When I run my code it just checks one value by that the max and min ranges individually. My problem is I need it to make sure every value is within range then complete a task.

```
list=[10,15,20]
max=[30,10,30]
min=[5,2,10]
x=100
y=100
for j in range(3):
   if list[j] <= max[j] and list[j] >= min[j] and x < 419 and y < 419:
     c='true'
     print c
   else:
     c='false'
     print c
```

My output is:
     true
     false
     true

Comment: provide your input and output values

Comment: Would you mind stripping down the code to fit the MCVE rules? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I changed my code to a smaller example of what I meant and added the output.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer.

Then try this:

```
list=[10,15,20]
max=[30,10,30]
min=[5,2,10]
x=100
y=100

for number in range(len(max)):
    for j in range(3):
        if list[j] <= max[number] and list[j] >= min[number] and x < 419 and y < 419:
            continue
        else:
            print("false")
            break
```

A precondition for this solution is, that your min and max list have the same number of entries.

And you can read the docs about the control flow: 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Mace, what I need is to make sure that each value in the list array is between that range set by the max and min arrays. So for example the code I posted should just output false because the list array is correct for the 1st and 3rd values but not the 2nd